# Combine for loop with timing events in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var interval = setInterval(function(){
        alert(i);
      }, 2000);
    }
```

What I would like to achieve is to have an alert every 2 sec displaying first 0, then 1 and lastly 2.

Instead I have to wait for quite long before I have 3 alerts all displaying the number 3. Where is my code wrong?

Comment: So many duplicates. Choose one: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+settimeout+loop

Comment: Does it need to be a forloop? Otherwise...http://jsfiddle.net/joseftw/cmN7B/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is (yet again) more than one solution to this problem. But, lets first talk **why** your code doesn't work properly.

**Your code:**

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        alert(i);
    }, 2000);
}
```

..basically means that it will assign three `setInterval` calls to be executed after 2 seconds as fast as the for loop is placing them to the queue. So basically, all your calls runs really fast after 2 seconds, only few milliseconds or less between them. Moreover, `setInterval` means that it will be called as long as `clearInterval` is called to the variable it is assigned with. In other words, your code never stops executing the alert, because you are never calling `clearInterval`. Finally, your `alert(i)` will always display value of 3, because it is the last value of `i` when execution moves away from the `for` loop.

To improve your code, you could remove the for loop entirely and just let `setInterval` run as long as the value of `i` is alerted three times; At that point, you just call `clearInterval` to the value which has handle to `setInterval` and the job is finished.

**Working code:**

```
// value to output
var i = 0,
    // starting setInterval and assigning its handle to variable interval,
    // it is used to clear the interval when execution should be finished
    interval = setInterval(function () {

        // alert value of i and increase it by 1
        alert(i++);

        // if i is equals to 3, no more calls
        if(i === 3) {

            // clear the interval so method won't be called in the future
            clearInterval(interval);

        }
    }, 2000);
```

**[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8A3q8/1/)**

Cheers, hopefully you learnt something new today.

Answer (score 1):

**1.1** Without `for` loop + without initial delay ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n9v37/)):

```
var i = 0;
var showAlert = function(){
    alert(i);
    i++;
    if(i < 3){
        setTimeout(function(){
            showAlert();
        }, 2000);
    }
};
showAlert();
```

**1.2** Without `for` loop + with initial delay ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6U3q2/)):

```
var i = 0;
var showAlert = function(){
    if(i < 3){
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert(i);
            i++;
            showAlert();
        }, 2000);
    }
};
showAlert();
```

**2.1** With `for` loop + without initial delay ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8A3q8/)):

```
function setAlert(k){
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert(k);
    },k * 2000);
}
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setAlert(i);
}
```

**2.2** With `for` loop + with initial delay ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hx84n/)):

```
function setAlert(k){
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert(k);
    },(k + 1) * 2000);
}
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setAlert(i);
}
```

Comment: I doubt that you are doing this correctly, your first alert appears without 2 sec wait time.

Comment: Well, the Qer should clarify this. The first one needs a delay or not. It's simple to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Without forloop:

```
var number = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    alert(number);
    number++;
    if(number === 3) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 2000);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/joseftw/cmN7B/2/)

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, I would go with setTimout, you know that you want 3 alerts.
2. Second problem is a bit stranger. You are calling async function, setTimeout/setInterval and referring to the original i of the for loop inside of the setTimeout callback. That will not work because at the time of the timeout invocation the for loop has already finished and i var will be 3. One solution is to wrapp the async function in a self invoking anonymous function with params that you need inside async function. In our case we call it with i.

Solution:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert(i);
        }, 2000 * i);
    })(i);
}
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44qLC/1/)